# Video filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing

I'm trying to reproduce [this paper](http://fedcsis.eucip.pl/proceedings/pliks/188.pdf)'s results using MATLAB. I need to apply a filter to RGB channels' sequence of a video (there is 1 color value per frame per channel which corresponds to the sum of values of all pixels of that channel in that frame, i.e. if there are 200 frames I have a 200x3 matrix, the columns are RGB and the rows are the frames).

I'm supposed to filter the 3 signals I get and apply PCA and ICA.

I'm new to signal processing and I've been trying to use FDATool and the filter function but I can't do it right. I should make a FIR bandpass filter, 0.5-3.7 Hz, 32-point Hamming window. I made a filter like this with FDATool but I'm not sure about Fs and I can't get a coherent result.

I'm doing this (which is probably wrong):

```
filt_channels = filter(my_coefficients,1,channels);
```

where channels is my 200x3 matrix.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each channel is defined like this in an image object, img:

```
R = img(:,:,1);
G = img(:,:,2);
B = img(:,:,3);
```

You should be able to export from FDATool to a filter object. You can then apply the filter using the following syntax:

```
Rfilt=filter2(Object_name, R);
Gfilt=filter2(Object_name, G);
Bfilt=filter2(Object_name, B);
```

where Object_name is the resultant filter object and R, G, and B are what you want to filter.

If you want to view them to see if you are getting the results you want, form a matrix, A, and use `imshow(A)`. Do this for each frame in your video stream.

Ex.

```
filtImg = [];

filtImg(:,:,1) = Rfilt;
filtImg(:,:,2) = Gfilt;
filtImg (:,:,3) = Bfilt;

imshow(filtImg)
```

Each channel (R, G, then B) can be filtered like this separately on each frame and then you can apply the *processpca* Matlab function to the resulting RGB matrix, filtImg.

**References**
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/301472
http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/processpca.html

Comment: I tried applying the filter to [this](http://i45.tinypic.com/2e2lzic.jpg) and I got [this](http://i46.tinypic.com/11bkqpi.jpg). I don't know what to do to apply the filter correctly.

Comment: I want to apply the filter on all frames, I have 3 signals which are R,G and B channels, where each point on each signal is the sum of pixels of one channel in a certain frame. In the grey scale plot I have 100 frames (horizontal axis).

Comment: It looks like since you have a 2D signal, you have to use filter2 instead of filter (http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/71142/1.php). Use that on each signal (R,G,&B) in each frame. The syntax is the same. I will update my post. If you are wondering about how your filter should operate then it sounds like you may need to refer to a good reference on FIR filters (http://www.eas.uccs.edu/wickert/ece2610/lecture_notes/ece2610_chap5.pdf) and another with DSP context (http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/firWindowing.html).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I'm not trying to filter images, I'm trying to filter 1 pixel per frame, for all frames. In grey scale, it's just a vector with 100 values (for 100 frames). The frequencies that should pass are certain frequencies of change in color intensity.

Comment: In that case, you can just use res1 = filter(Object_name,channels(:,1)); res2 = filter(Object_name,channels(:,2)); res3 = filter(Object_name,channels(:,3)); 

In the paper, "Independent component analysis and principal component analysis were conducted for different sets of data," so we can assess each of the RGB independently. From there, do the processpca on the channels. "Signals from three
channels R, G and B were an input to ICA and PCA."

Comment: That's what I did, but the result doesn't look right. The filtered signals look just like the one I linked in my first comment. I used a different video than the one in the paper but it's relatively similar.

Comment: You mention that you do not know what Fs is in FDAtools. That is your sampling frequency. Ex. your image stream is 50 fps, so Fs = 50. What did you put for this?

Comment: Thanks. I was confused but I had that intuition so I put the right number which is 30 for my videos. But I still can't use the filter.

Comment: To figure this out from here, my best advice is to try a few things to debug or assess your code. First you could try and make a simpler filter using fir1(), fir2(), or even butter() to filter your same signal. Then try to design the same in FDATools. Compare the results to determine if you are correctly using FDATools. If nothing strange shows up there you could go a step further and try and implement the entire filter outside of FDATools using fir1() and hamming() to determine whether or not you are getting the correct output. I think going through these will show you where the problem is.

Comment: In the end I tried MATLAB's filter builder (filterbuilder) and it did what I wanted. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: Not a problem. Wish I could have been of more help.

Comment: You were helpful. I was lost because I'm new to signal processing, and I lack background, so I didn't even know if I was calling the function correctly. I didn't try everything you said because I don't have time to finish this work but I'll consider your advice in the future. Thanks!